QGIS rotate/translate features on several layers with different geometries simultaneously
I am working in QGIS with three vector layers (points, lines, polygons) and an aerial image. The features from these three layers are "connected", i.e. they should stay in the same position relative to each other.
I have to manually move / rotate subsets of these features to match certain fix points on the arial image, maintaining their relative position to each other. E.g. translate some features of different geometry type together a few meters up and left. Rotate a few features by 13°.

Whoever knows these actions (selecting a group of geometries and transforming them together or individually) from PowerPoint or vector editing tools (Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape) knows how you would want to do it: Simply drag and drop the group together, nudge with arrow key, rotate while holding down Ctrl; and ideally there is a checkbox somewhere to allow rotating all objects in place.
But QGIS offers several hurdles with different geometries/layer not being processable together (to my knowledge).
How would you recommend doing this?

I came up with two options, both not being really "good" options:
Option A: I can do this with the Advanced Digitizing tools layer by layer (first move the polygons, then the lines, then the points), but this is imprecise / circumstancial: I have to remember the exact relative positions and try to reproduce them by hand. Rotation (in place) allows for typing in actual values, so I can rotate "exactly" by the same amount. But moving (translation) doesn't have a similar box.
I also tested working on multiple layers simultaneously: Although I can select multiple features from different layers that are all in editing mode, transformations are only applied to the first selected layer (even when highlighting several layers). There also is a plugin for multiselecting several layers simultaneously, but not more than that.

Option B: I can use the processing tools "Rotate" and "Translate". The processing tool "Affine transformation" could do both, but doesn't work, since it neither rotates by the center of the polygons nor does it allow me to set an anchor for rotation; seemingly it rotates by the origin of the used CRS or some other unknown point far away, since it results in huge displacements even when rotating a few degrees.
Using this approach also is exact, I can use the same parameters for all three layers, applying it only to the selected features. But it is ultra-circumstancial, since these tools always "Copy and move / copy and rotate", meaning they create a new layer with the moved/rotated features. I have to go through several extra steps (multiple times, i.e. for each different geometry type!): apply transformation, merge new resulting layer with old layer, delete old features within that layer, delete the old layer, delete the layer with the "temporary features".



This question asks a similar thing, recommending merging the layers. Since we deal with geometries of different types, unfortunately this is not an option.
I also checked some YouTube tutorials e.g. on "Multi-Layers" (by Hal Hart, I realized this isn't really a thing - he's just referring to multiple layers) and "editing" but this issue seems to be addressed nowhere.

While it doesn't solve your entire problem, have you tried using the "Edit features in place" setting. This allows for Rotate/Translate to be applied to features within the layer, which avoids creating new layers and having to merge them?

This solution could be a little bit complex and long, it only work with single part geometries and with polygon without inner rings. If you need to translate features multiple times then it could work for you. The idea is to convert all geometries from all layers to a single layer of point type, with symbology for each feature, so that you can edit multiple features at the same time, keeping the necessary information to then generate each layer with its geometry.
First create a new integer field, name it id and calculate it with this expression $id, this must be done in each layer (points, lines and polygons). Then calculate a text field, call it layer and fill it with a string that differentiates each layer, I will use the expression 'point' to calculate it in the point layer, then 'line' for the line layer and do the same with the polygons. The attribute table of each layer will look like this:

Now convert the polygon and the lines to points with the Extract vertices QGIS tool and then merge with the Merge vector layers tool the point layer with the results of extracting the vertices from the lines and the polygons. Please do not change the name of the output layer of the merge tool (Merged), that name will be used to refer to that layer later.

Now apply symbology, use single symbol and add three symbol layers of type geometry generator.

The first symbol (descending) must be set to point geometry type and the expression is the following: if("layer"='point', $geometry, NULL).

In the second symbol set line as geometry type, use this expression:
if(
    "vertex_index" = 0 OR "vertex_index" IS NULL,
    make_line(aggregate(
        'Merged',
        'array_agg',
        $geometry,
        filter:="id" = attribute(@parent, 'id') AND "layer" = 'line',
        order_by:="vertex_index"
    )),
    NULL
)

And the third set the geometry to polygon and use this expression:
if(
    "vertex_index" = 0 OR "vertex_index" IS NULL,
    make_polygon(make_line(aggregate(
        'Merged',
        'array_agg',
        $geometry,
        filter:="id" = attribute(@parent, 'id') AND "layer" = 'polygon',
        order_by:="vertex_index"
    ))),
    NULL
)

Now you can use the advanced digitizing tools to edit the layer.

When you finish all the editions you can separate each layer.
To get the points use the Extract by attribute tool to extract all features (from the "Merged" layer) where the layer attribute is equal to point.
To get the lines use the Geometry by expression tool on the "Merged" layer, set the output geometry type to line and use the same expression that was used to symbolize the lines and then run the "Remove null geometries" tool on the result.
To get polygons do the same that we did with lines but change the output geometry type and use the expression for polygons, then remove null geometries.
